# Image comparison and visual testing for Windows desktop application and C# with the usage of WinAPppDriver

Tags: selenium, opencv, sikuli, winappdriver, visual-testing

Please help in choosing a tool for testing watermark/image overlay. The transparency can be 0%, it should not be a problem.

The application under test is a WPF desktop application on Windows, the autotests are written in Winappdriver + C#, now it looks like I have to take a screenshot of a specific element and compare the actual image with the ideal sample by a mask.

The product under test is a video camera with the ability to insert a logotype/watermark and/or additional details (date/name/address) on the image and video. The task is to verify automatically the correctness of the inserted logo and the correctness of the inserted details in the image/video (size, color, if the logo was mirrored after insert or whatever if a name was entered badly...).

At the moment I am thinking about using OpenCV or Sikuli. I know that Appium had something similar but it probably won't work with my driver.

It is also unclear how and what can be tested with video. Just to take one frame randomly and make a test for it as for an image?

Many thanks for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a complete answer to you your questions but a few words on how Sikuli works and what might be a disadvantage, if I understand your needs correctly. First of all, Sikuli is using OpenCV internally by calling the `Imgproc.matchTemplate()` function. There is not much control over it from Sikuli but you can set a minimum similarity score that varies between 0 (everything will match) and 1 (pixel perfect comparison). Given you intend to use it for video originated patterns, you'd want to be somewhere in the middle. Having said that, I am not sure what quality of comparison you'd like to obtain so not sure if the minimum similarity by itself will be enough.

Another thought is to integrate the OpenCv lib itself in your code and use it directly. This is not an easy task and some basic understand of image processing techniques might be required.